# ReceiveAsync's CancellationToken paramtere is doing timeout even if the web socket client is still connected

Tags: c#, .net, clientwebsocket

How do I make `ClientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync` timeout in 5 seconds *only* if the web socket client is not connected? The current behavior is that it timeouts no matter what conditions are met, i.e. whether the web socket client is connected or not, which is not the behavior I expect.

```cs
var timeOut = new CancellationTokenSource(5000).Token;
var receiveResult = await _clientWebSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.Memory, timeOut).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the keep alive interval to 5 secs:

`_clientWebSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);`

Comment: When I disconnect Wi-Fi, `ReceiveAsync` throws a WebSocketException (prematurely closed) in like 30 seconds or so, but it is surely not 5 seconds. That's the behavior I want to change.